# Converting Non-HA Hadoop cluster to HA cluster

Tags: hadoop, hbase, hdfs, hadoop2, high-availability

I've a Non-HA Hadoop setup with 3 nodes: A NameNode and 2 DataNodes. The NameNode is a server with 4GB memory and 20GB hard disk while each DataNode has 8GB memory and 100GB hard disk.

Now I need to convert this to a HA cluster. I've read about two ways of doing this: using Quorum Journal Manager and using a shared storage.

What is the best way of doing this from above two?
 
How many additional nodes do I required on each approach?
How can I minimize need of adding new nodes using existing nodes (Is it recommended to use DataNodes and NameNodes as JournalNodes)?

I'm using Apache Hadoop version: 2.7.2 and Apache Hbase version: 1.2.4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What is the best way of doing this from above two?

QJM (Quorum Journal Manager) is recommended choice unless you have an highly reliable and fault tolerant shared storage.

> How many additional nodes do I required on each approach?

**One** for the standby Namenode. You can run the JournalNodes and Zookeeper nodes along with the Datanodes.

Comment: Do the namenodes maintain the metadata in memory also while writing the same in the JournalNodes for a HA cluster so as to serve fast, or every time a client requests then they read the metadata journal node to serve the request?

Comment: Namenodes always hold the metadata in their memory when in function.